# Retrieve the ID of a row when i click on a ImageButton (telerik)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have in my grid a ImageButton in each rows. When i click on it, i need to retrieve the ID of the selected row.

My grid is fulfilled using an ObjectDataSource.

This is the column i'm talking about:

```
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ImageColumnDetails">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonDetails" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/cle-outil_white.gif"
                     ToolTip="Détails du ticket"
                     OnClientClick='<%# Eval("idAgir","openRadWin({0})") %>;return false;'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

As you see, i need to specify the IdAgir in my aspx page to pass it by URL to a JS function.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to include idAgir in your DataSource, going with the implementation you're attempting this should work:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="ImageColumnDetails">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonDetails" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/cle-outil_white.gif"
                         ToolTip="Détails du ticket"
                         OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("openRadWin({0});return false;",DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.idAgir"))%> '/>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

-

I personally usually use this approach, and modify my columns on the server side, but I don't really see the difference.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="User Name" UniqueName="UserName" SortExpression="UserName">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:HyperLink ID="UserNameLink" runat="server" CssClass="lnkAction icon_toolbar_edit_blue"></asp:HyperLink>
     </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>


protected void radGrid_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            var dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            HyperLink userNameLink = (HyperLink)dataBoundItem.FindControl("UserNameLink");
            userNameLink.Attributes["href"] = "#";
            userNameLink.Attributes["onclick"] = String.Format("selectRow('{0}');return ShowEditUser('{1}');", dataBoundItem.ItemIndex, dataBoundItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[dataBoundItem.ItemIndex]["id"]);
            userNameLink.Text = dataBoundItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[dataBoundItem.ItemIndex]["UserName"].ToString();
        }
    }
```